# error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::string' and more errors

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, travis-ci, clang++

I'm running a build in Travis CI, and during the compilation, this error occurs. I tried specifying the C++ compiler and tried using g++ but that resulted in more errors.

```sh
$ clang -I ./jsoncpp/include/ -L ./jsoncpp/build/debug/lib -std=c++14 -v test.cpp -o buildtest.exe
...
./IBMWatson.h:79:44: error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::string'
      (aka 'basic_string<char>') through variadic function; call will abort at
      runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, apikey); /* Par...
                                                         ^
./IBMWatson.h:81:39: error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::string'
      (aka 'basic_string<char>') through variadic function; call will abort at
      runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url); /* Sets Regio...
                                                    ^
./IBMWatson.h:104:102: warning: result of comparison against a string literal is
      unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare]
  ...+ response.length(), &root, &err) || funcName == "returnVoices" || funcN...
...
4 warnings and 4 errors generated.
The command "clang -I ./jsoncpp/include/ -L ./jsoncpp/build/debug/lib -std=c++14 -v test.cpp -o buildtest.exe" exited with 1.
```

Comment: Try this apikey.c_str(), url.c_str()

Comment: It works, but now it outputs `undefined reference`

Comment: @PySnoo Use `-lcurl` in `clang` options.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`curl_easy_setopt` is a C function, where *variadic* actually means the `<cstdarg>`'s `...` parameter. It accepts only trivial types, which `std::string` is not (i.e., it cannot be copied with `memcpy`, and instead, a non-trivial copy-constructor is involved); otherwise the behavior is undefined or only conditionally supported. In order to pass a string value, use its `const char*` representation obtained with `c_str()`:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, apikey.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

Comment: Good catch. It seems that some other compilers must check for an implicit conversion to a trivial type as gcc doesn't complain about this behavior.